# Is this polynomial solvable by radicals?

Tags: polynomials, roots

The polynomial

$p(x) = x^6-9x^4-4x^3+27x^2-36x-23$.

has at least one (real, irrational) root that is expressible by radicals (can you find it?).

Are all the roots of $p$ expressible by radicals and if so, how can one find the expressions?

Comment: My reasoning is that if there is one, there is a second. If there are two, then you can write the above as a product of a quadratic and a quartic ie all roots are expressible by radicals.

Comment: Wolfram doesn't find that root : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=x6%E2%88%929x4%E2%88%924x3%2B27x2%E2%88%9236x%E2%88%9223%20%3D%200   Not sure how we could!

Comment: Typo perhaps? The equation $-x^6 - 9x^4-4x^3+27x^2-36x+23 = 0$ has for root 1.

Comment: No typo there. I can give the root if you want.

Comment: @user: I think your reasoning is suspect.

Comment: Isn't it the case that where radical expression appears in a solution, replacing it with any of the other roots of that expression must also be a solution? Hence there can never be just a single radical solution.

Comment: What do you mean by the "roots of that expression"?

Comment: I mean as a square root has two solutions, a cube root three, etc. Any of the square roots, any of the cube roots could be used. Sorry I'm not explaining this well but I think you can see it in GEdgar's answer. The factors are $(x-a\sqrt{3} - b\sqrt[3]{2})$ where $a$ is any sqaure root of 1 and $b$ is any cube root of 1.

Comment: ... or $x-a-b$ where $a$ is any squareroot of 3 and b is any cuberoot of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maple says
$$
16(x^6-9x^4-4x^3+27x^2-36x-23) =
\left( i\sqrt {3}\sqrt [3]{2}-2\,\sqrt {3}-\sqrt [3]{2}-2\,x
 \right)  \\
\left( i\sqrt {3}\sqrt [3]{2}+2\,x+2\,\sqrt {3}+\sqrt [3]{2}
 \right)  \left( i\sqrt {3}\sqrt [3]{2}-2\,\sqrt {3}+\sqrt [3]{2}+2\,x
 \right)  \\
\left( i\sqrt {3}\sqrt [3]{2}+2\,\sqrt {3}-\sqrt [3]{2}-2\,x
 \right)  \left( x+\sqrt {3}-\sqrt [3]{2} \right)  \left( -x+\sqrt {3}
+\sqrt [3]{2} \right) 
$$

Comment: Maple beats Wolfram